# best data structure for storing large number of numeric fields

Tags: c#, data-structures

I am working with a class, say Widget, that has a large number of numeric real world attributes (eg, height, length, weight, cost, etc.).  There are different types of widgets (sprockets, cogs, etc.), but each widget shares the exact same attributes (the values will be different by widget, of course, but they all have a weight, weight, etc.).  I have 1,000s of each type of widget (1,000 cogs, 1,000 sprockets, etc.)

I need to perform a lot of calculations on these attributes (say calculating the weighted average of the attributes for 1000s of different widgets).  For the weighted averages, I have different weights for each widget type (ie, I may care more about length for sprockets than for cogs).

Right now, I am storing all the attributes in a Dictionary< string, double>  within each widget (the widgets have an enum that specifies their type: cog, sprocket, etc.).  I then have some calculator classes that store weights for each attribute as a Dictionary< WidgetType, Dictionary< string, double >>.  To calculate the weighted average for each widget, I simply iterate through its attribute dictionary keys like:

```
double weightedAvg = 0.0;
foreach (string attibuteName in widget.Attributes.Keys)
{
    double attributeValue = widget.Attributes[attributeName];
    double attributeWeight = calculator.Weights[widget.Type][attributeName];
    weightedAvg += (attributeValue * attributeWeight);
}
```

So this works fine and is pretty readable and easy to maintain, but is very slow for 1000s of widgets based on some profiling.  My universe of attribute names is known and will not change during the life of the application, so I am wondering what some better options are.  The few I can think of:

1) Store attribute values and weights in double []s.  I think this is probably the most efficient option, but then I need to make sure the arrays are always stored in the correct order between widgets and calculators. This also decouples the data from the metadata so I will need to store an array (?) somewhere that maps between the attribute names and the index into double [] of attribute values and weights.

2) Store attribute values and weights in immutable structs.  I like this option because I don't have to worry about the ordering and the data is "self documenting".  But is there an easy way to loop over these attributes in code?  I have almost 100 attributes, so I don't want to hardcode all those in the code.  I can use reflection, but I worry that this will cause even a larger penalty hit since I am looping over so many widgets and will have to use reflection on each one.

Any other alternatives?

Comment: When you say you need to loop over 100 attributes, do you mean that each class has 100 attributes?  Or do you mean that you have to loop over a 100 instances of the class on a single attribute (weight, e. g.)?  I would think that a base class that each of the more specific classes would inherit would be appropriate and a single method that does the calculation for a single widget.

Comment: You could store everything in a matrix (see http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/ for a free nuget package that is excellent), then you implement properties that get and set values directly to the matrix. That way you get ease of access, but performance in computing the calculations.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, Right now I only have 1 Widget class and the type of the widget is just stored as a property (enum valued) of the class. I can make the widget types different sublcasses, but I don't think that will fix my issue.  In any case, to answer your question, the Widget class has 100 attributes.  So to calculate the weighted average for any one widget, I need to perform 100 multiplications & additions.  But I am also performing this weighted average calculation on 1000s of different widget instances.

Comment: do they all have the same attribute columns or different?

Comment: @MeirionHughes, thanks for the suggestion.  Would I create a new matrix for each widget instance?  Or are you suggesting I create one "global" attribute matrix (with num_widget rows and num_attribute columns) and then have logic in each widget instance's get/set methods to directly access the matrix?  The second method sounds interesting, but I am not sure where I would store the global matrix and whether or not the overhead of the custom getter/setter methods would be better than the overhead from the current Dictionary version.

Comment: hmm you'd probably be better off with a list of vectors (double array)... then use Parralel.For over the list... its super simple. Having my dinner in a bit, if no one else answer with this I'll post an anwser.

Comment: @MeirionHughes, all Widgets (regardless of type) will have the same exact attributes and the attributes are known ahead of time (ie, at compile time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three possibilities come immediately to mind. The first, which I think you rejected too readily, is to have individual fields in your class. That is, individual `double` values named `height`, `length`, `weight`, `cost`, etc. You're right that it would be more code to do the calculations, but you wouldn't have the indirection of dictionary lookup.

Second is to ditch the dictionary in favor of an array. So rather than a `Dictionary<string, double>`, you'd just have a `double[]`. Again, I think you rejected this too quickly. You can easily replace the string dictionary keys with an enumeration. So you'd have:

```
enum WidgetProperty
{
    First = 0,
    Height = 0,
    Length = 1,
    Weight = 2,
    Cost = 3,
    ...
    Last = 100
}
```

Given that and an array of `double`, you can easily go through all of the values for each instance:

```
for (int i = (int)WidgetProperty.First; i < (int)WidgetProperty.Last; ++i)
{
    double attributeValue = widget.Attributes[i];
    double attributeWeight = calculator.Weights[widget.Type][i];
    weightedAvg += (attributeValue * attributeWeight);
}
```

Direct array access is going to be significantly faster than accessing a dictionary by string.

Finally, you can optimize your dictionary access a little bit. Rather than doing a `foreach` on the keys and then doing a dictionary lookup, do a `foreach` on the dictionary itself:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> kvp in widget.Attributes)
{
    double attributeValue = kvp.Value;
    double attributeWeight = calculator.Weights[widget.Type][kvp.Key];
    weightedAvg += (attributeValue * attributeWeight);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jim, this answer is great.  I had not even considered that you can loop over the enum that way.  I had considered replacing the string keys in the Dictionary with enums instead, but using the enum + array seems even better.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate weighted averages without looping or reflection, one way would be to calculate the weighted average of the individual attributes and store them in some place. This should happen while you are creating instance of the widget. Following is a sample code which needs to be modified to your needs.
Also, for further processing of the the widgets themselves, you can use data parallelism. see my other response in this thread.

```
public enum WidgetType { }

public class Claculator { }

public class WeightStore
{
    static Dictionary<int, double> widgetWeightedAvg = new Dictionary<int, double>();
    public static void AttWeightedAvgAvailable(double attwightedAvg, int widgetid)
    {
        if (widgetWeightedAvg.Keys.Contains(widgetid))
            widgetWeightedAvg[widgetid] += attwightedAvg;
        else
            widgetWeightedAvg[widgetid] = attwightedAvg;
    }
}

public class WidgetAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public double Value { get; }
    public WidgetAttribute(string name, double value, WidgetType type, int widgetId)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        double attWeight = Calculator.Weights[type][name];
        WeightStore.AttWeightedAvgAvailable(Value*attWeight, widgetId);
    }
}

public class CogWdiget
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public WidgetAttribute height { get; set; }
    public WidgetAttribute wight { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public void BuildCogWidgets()
    {
        CogWdiget widget = new CogWdiget();
        widget.Id = 1;
        widget.height = new WidgetAttribute("height", 12.22, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: so you are suggesting caching the weighted values once (at object creation)?  Thanks, that is a useful idea that I had not thought about.  I am not sure it will work in my case just because there are many, many different calculators and most may only be called on a subset of widgets (which I won't know ahead of time), so I would end up caching lots of data that may never get used.  But I will consider it.

Answer (score 0):

As it is always the case with data normalization, is that choosing your normalization level determines a good part of the performance. It looks like you would have to go from your current model to another model or a mix.

Better performance for your scenario is possible when you do not process this with the C# side, but with the database instead. You then get the benefit of indexes, no data transfer except the wanted result, plus 100000s of man hours already spent on performance optimization.

Comment: The OP didn't mention anything about a database and this seems more like a comment than an asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Data Parallelism supported by the .net 4 and above.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608(v=vs.110).aspx

An excerpt from the above link

When a parallel loop runs, the TPL partitions the data source so that the loop can operate on multiple parts concurrently. Behind the scenes, the Task Scheduler partitions the task based on system resources and workload. When possible, the scheduler redistributes work among multiple threads and processors if the workload becomes unbalanced